# Can I trigger a button to visibly click with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code that was given to me as a solution earlier. What I would like to do is to make it so when the user clicks the ENTER key (13) that this then makes an input button on the form appear to be clicked. Is this possible with JQuery. Could I make it look like the user clicked the button and have the button change just for a very short time?

```
$('#target').keypress(function(event) {
 if (event.which == '13') {
     //Do something with the enter press
 }
```

Comment: what you exactly mean with 'appear to be clicked' ??

Comment: Avoid catching Enter keypresses. This plays badly with tools like IMEs which can fire an Enter keypress that shouldn't submit a form. Much better if you can to just have a normal form with an `<input type="submit"/>`.

Answer (score 3):

Use trigger method

```
$('#target').keypress(function(event) {
 if (event.which == '13') {
     $(<YOUR_BUTTON_SELECTOR>).trigger('click');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If by *"input button"* you mean an `<input type="submit">` element, or a `<button>` element, then no you can't.

You'd need to create a custom button.

And then if you do a custom button, it will depend on how you're changing its appearance during clicks.

If you're using `mousedown/mouseup`, then you'll need to trigger those events.

```
$(selector).mousedown();
$(selector).mouseup();
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to style a custom button, or a `<div>` that contains your `<input>` button, you can use `.css()` to add a color:

```
element.css('background','blue'); 
setTimeout(function(){
    element.css('background','none');
}, 1000);
```

The `setTimeout` will give a delay of 1 second (1000 milliseconds) before the background is reset.

Alternatively, you could add/remove a class, which is probably better.

```
element.addClass('active'); 
setTimeout(function(){
    element.removeClass('active');
}, 1000);
```

---

**EDIT:** It looks like there's more support than I thought for coloring browser generated UI buttons. So you can use the same techniques above to color the buttons directly.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it seems this way. I wonder if I can change a background property for a second and then change it back. Something like change the font color to blue and then back to black.

Comment: @Derek WWW: If again you're talking about the UI element supplied by the browser, then not in any cross-platform way. If you're talking about a custom button, or if you want to put your `<input>` button in a `<div>`, then you can change the background using `.css()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Derek WWW: I may have been wrong about the background: It looks like there is support for more browsers than I thought with respect to changing the style of browser UI buttons. You could use the same techniques, just apply them to the buttons themselves.